# How do I initialize a File type variable so that I avoid the "LateInitializationError" error?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I keep getting the error whenever I try logging in an existing user to my program but I can create new users just fine which are signed in automatically upon creation. I've narrowed it down to the line  that contains the "late File _userImageFile;" variable. Not sure how to initialize it properly. Other things I tried were giving it a null check "!" and making the variable nullable.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chat_app2/widgets/pickers/user_image_picker.dart';

class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  AuthForm(this.submitFn, this.isLoading);

  final bool isLoading;
  final void Function(String email, String password, String username,
      File image, bool isLogin, BuildContext ctx) submitFn;

  @override
  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _isLogin = true;
  String _userEmail = '';
  String _userName = '';
  String _userPassword = '';
  late File _userImageFile;

  void _pickedImage(File image) {
    _userImageFile = image;
  }

  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (_userImageFile == null && !_isLogin) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text("please pick an image"),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      return;
    }

    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      widget.submitFn(
        _userEmail.trim(),
        _userName.trim(),
        _userPassword.trim(),
        _userImageFile,
        _isLogin,
        context,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  if (!_isLogin) UserImagePicker(_pickedImage),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email address',
                    ),
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userEmail = value!;
                    },
                  ),
                  if (!_isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('userName'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
                          return 'Please enter at least four characters';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userName = value!;
                      },
                    ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be at least seven characters long';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userPassword = value!;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  if (widget.isLoading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  if (!widget.isLoading)
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Sign up'),
                      onPressed: _trySubmit,
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      )),
                    ),
                  if (!widget.isLoading)
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text(_isLogin
                          ? 'Create new account'
                          : 'I already have an account'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                        });
                      },
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are already doing null check, make the variable nullable.

```dart
File? _userImageFile;
```

Snippet

```dart
class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _isLogin = true;
  String _userEmail = '';
  String _userName = '';
  String _userPassword = '';
  File? _userImageFile;

  void _pickedImage(File image) {
    _userImageFile = image;
  }

  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false;
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (_userImageFile == null && !_isLogin) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text("please pick an image"),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      return;
    }

    if (isValid && _userImageFile != null) {
      _formKey.currentState?.save();
      widget.submitFn(
        _userEmail.trim(),
        _userName.trim(),
        _userPassword.trim(),
        _userImageFile!,
        _isLogin,
        context,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  if (!_isLogin) UserImagePicker(_pickedImage),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email address',
                    ),
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userEmail = value??"";
                    },
                  ),
                  if (!_isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('userName'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
                          return 'Please enter at least four characters';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userName = value??"";
                      },
                    ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be at least seven characters long';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userPassword = value??"";
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  if (widget.isLoading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  if (!widget.isLoading)
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Sign up'),
                      onPressed: _trySubmit,
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      )),
                    ),
                  if (!widget.isLoading)
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text(_isLogin
                          ? 'Create new account'
                          : 'I already have an account'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                        });
                      },
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error

"Exception caught by gesture 
Null check operator used on a null value"

Comment: While submitting the form or initially ? try `final isValid = _formKey.currentState?.validate()??false;`

Comment: when logging in. Where should I put that in my code?

Comment: try `final isValid = _formKey.currentState?.validate()??false;`

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: try to paste attached snippet and make sure to save the file and then rebuild the app

Comment: I tried the code snippet you posted now the error is gone but It still won't log in the user.

Comment: try to debug, recheck the logic of validation and bool

Comment: The debug console doesn't show anything while I tried logging in a user acc.

Comment: Sorry can't help on this new issue, you can create new question with minimal-proper  snippet.